# Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table

I have some Python code that makes Raster Attribute Tables for GeoTiffs using GDAL.

In ArcGIS I can see these attribute tables fine and they behave how I like (as classifications) but in QGIS the whole concept of an attribute table seems to be missing.

Is there any way to access a RAT in QGIS?

Comment: There is a crowdfunding effort to implement RATs at Kartoza:  https://kartoza.com/en/crowdfunding/raster-vat-table-support-in-qgis/  Make a pledge!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This feature request might fill your needs: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/22427

Comment: If I understand correctly this feature still still doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, not yet implemented. Evidently is not something asked by many.

Answer (score 7):

Good news!  A Raster Attribute Table plugin (experimental) is now available.  There's also a Youtube video introduction at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nARp6yxRt68

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's currently missing from the plugin repo? Is there some other homepage for this?

Comment: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RasterAttributeTable/

Comment: https://github.com/noaa-ocs-hydrography/qgis-raster-attribute-table-plugin

Answer (score 3):

There is still no such function in QGIS as raster attributive table (as it was in ArcMap). However, you can get similar output by running `Raster layer unique values report`. This function counts unique values (which is perfect for integer rasters) and even calculates the area.

[image]

The output will look smth like:

```
Extent: 103.2208100000000002,52.1505000000000010 : 141.5203300000000013,73.7999700000000018

Projection: WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

Width in pixels: 33991 (units per pixel 0.00112675)

Height in pixels: 19214 (units per pixel 0.00112675)

Total pixel count: 653103074

NODATA pixel count: 339328216

Value   Pixel count Area (deg²)
0   1549588 1.96732049625739
1   248748550   315.8053113661866
2   17323972    21.99410759001047
3   24404810    30.98377305468765
4   3532094 4.48426350804714
5   7962170 10.10858385305366
6   10253674    13.01782346155333
```