# How to symbolize raster with field values in QGIS or GRASS GIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0, qgis-2.14, grass-6.4

I have a raster with ten field values.

In ArcGIS I can open and select one of the field values for symbology and it show me the values from that field.

**How can I handle this in QGIS?**

I share a picture for a better comprehension.

ArcGIS

[image]

QGIS

[image]

Screenshot showing the six files of raster file.

[image]

Comment: What format is your raster? Most raster formats don't have multiple field values like that.

Comment: i think this might be a paletted raster... try changing type of renderer (tipo de renderizador) to 'Paletted' (En paleta) and see if you get a list of values and labels?

Comment: @StevenKay it's a raster with an attribute table. They are supported by ArcGIS and GDAL, but not by QGIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis)

Comment: the_skua the format is .tiff, I edited the question and post an image with the six files it has.

Comment: Looking in the post from @Luke, they say that is not implement in QGIS. I don't know if the question is the same, this is for symbology and the other is for acces to raster attribute table in a raster. Who can tell me if I have to remove this?  Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the attribute table of a raster in QGIS because until now building raster attribute table (RAT) is not supported in QGIS.

Unfortunately, QGIS lacks this feature compared to ArcGIS, and as @Luke indicated in his comment there is a question of [Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis) and a request for this feature was already submitted, but it is still not yet implemented.

Therefore, you cannot have a list of attribute table in the symbology of QGIS similar to what you can get in ArcGIS because simply there is no attribute table associated with raster data in QGIS.