# How to view raster attribute data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-attribute-table

I have a single band, 8-bit, unsigned integer tif (National Land Cover Data).  When I view it in Arcmap 10.4.1, I am given the opportunity to also view it's attribute table:

[image]

However, when I view this same tif in QGIS 2.16.3, there is no option to open the attribute table:

[image]

With QGIS I can also load the tif's .dbf file, which contains the attribute data, but I don't see how to join that to the tif.

In summary, how do I view a tif's associated attribute data?

Comment: AFAIK, this functionality is not yet implemented in QGIS. This (old) post is still valid : [Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis)

Comment: @ArMoraer Thanks for the link.  It shows that it's been a feature request for over 5 years.  Is there any way that I could up-vote the request to something more urgent than "nice to have"?  Who makes that determination, anyway?

Comment: Stu - here's a good summary: http://nyalldawson.net/2016/08/how-to-effectively-get-things-changed-in-qgis/