# AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

**Remember i am using Python Version 3.6.2 QGIS Version 3.2**

while running my code i am getting this error:

```
fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'pendingFields
```

**if i am using fields() instead of pendingFields() because of qgis version 3x**

getting this error:

```
fields = selectedLayer.fields()
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'fields
```

i am new in this field so please tell me properly what should i do

**here is my code:**

```
    filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
    output_file = open(filename, 'w')

    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
    fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]

    for f in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
        line = ','.join(unicode(f[x]) for x in fieldnames) + '\n'
        unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
        output_file.write(unicode_line)
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: i just simply created a plugin it didn't ask for QgsRasterLayer or QgsVectorLayer. from qt creator i design my plugin to take the layers raster or vector from my local system and it save output file but when ever i am saving output file i am getting this error

Comment: i am absolute beginners in QGIS so i am not getting it well                              what i want to do is ----- i created my plugin i just want to add some code in my mainPlugin.py file like print('hello') and want to run this in qgis so what should i do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not work with raster layers as they have neither fields (QGIS doesn't support raster attribute tables - [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis)) nor features.

`fields` (`pendingFields` in 2x) and `getFeatures` are methods of the [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=fields#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.fields) class.

So test if your layer has a `fields` method (i.e `if hasattr(selectedLayer, 'fields'): etc...` and ignore it if it doesn't.  i.e

```
filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
if hasattr(selectedLayer, 'fields'):

    fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
    fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]

    for f in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
        etc...
```

Comment: error gone but its not saving my output file. will you forgot to add
output_file = open(filename, 'w')   in second line.
After adding it on 2nd line output file showing in my system

Comment: The `etc...` in my code snippet represents the rest of your code, including the output. I didn't forget it, I deliberately didn't include it as it's not relevant to the question and to keep my answer simple.