# How do you check the attribute information of the tif image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, image, digital-image-processing

Where can I check the brightness value (DN) of the image stored as 'tif format' in QGIS? What is the way to add it to the attribute table?

Current progress:
Coordinates are assigned to each pixel of the raster image.

My plan:
The DN value of each pixel is added to the attribute table, and the DN value is classified and analyzed.

What I Need:

To check DN value in image, add DN value to attribute table.

Comment: Do any of the answers to this question help you? [Accessing raster attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use these two steps:

- Use the tool *Raster pixels to points*
  `Processing Toolbox > Vector creation > Raster pixels to points`
- Use *Add X/Y fields to layer* on the points layer
  `Processing Toolbox > Vector table > Add X/Y fields to layer`

[image]

[image]